# Color en los botones de la notificacion Android

Tags: android

tengo la siguiente notificacion, y me gustaria ponerle un color de fondo a los botones que dicen aceptar y leer mas. 
¿Como los seteo?

> NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

```
    style.setBigContentTitle("¡TITULO NOTIFICACION!");
    style.bigText(contenText);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
    Intent actionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActionActivity.class);
    Intent actionIntent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActionActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(123, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 222, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent actionPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 222, actionIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    nBuilder.setContentTitle("TITULO DE LA NOTIFICACION");
    nBuilder.setContentText("alalalalalalalalalalalala");
    nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    nBuilder.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    nBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name,55);
    nBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    nBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    nBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] {100, 2000, 500, 2000});
    nBuilder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 400, 400);
    nBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_nodonar, "¡ACEPTAR!", actionPendingIntent);
    nBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_nodonar, "Leer mas", actionPendingIntent2);
    nBuilder.setStyle(style);
    Notification notification = nBuilder.build();
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.notify(1,notification);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nicolas, agrega el modo como construyes tu notificacion

Comment: Ahi lo agregue. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Nico, buenas noches, mira, te recomiendo que no uses colores de fondo ni de icono para las notificaciones, ya que como especifica google, algunas versiones superiores a android lollipop 5.x  no van a verse, ya que solo se ven en blanco y negro 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podes encontrar mas info aca : [Notificaciones Google 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Stack overflow no me permite ponerte otro link :( lastima que sus reglas sean tan estrictas, pero puedes buscar en google esto : google materials , patterns notifications

espero ayudar, saludos