# Imagen dentro de la notificación Android

Tags: android

Tengo la siguiente notificación y su respectiva imagen. La misma notificación cuando se desliza hacia abajo aparece todo el texto. A su vez me gustaría que cuando se delize hacia abajo la imagen se agrande. ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer? Dejo marcado en rojo el lugar que quiero que ocupe la imagen verde.

[image: Esta es la imagen de ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr]

[image: Esta es la imagen de lo que quiero lograr, como se ve la imagen es mucho as grande]

Esta es la imagen de lo que quiero lograr, como se ve la imagen es mucho as grande

Comment: El problema que tienes aquí tiene la misma solución que el problema que indicas en esta pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14501/color-en-los-botones-de-la-notificacion-android Tienes que crearte un layout propio para las notificaciones. Aquí tienes la referencia en la documentación de google: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification

Answer (score 3):

Lo siento Nicolas, si deseas realizar esto nativamente esto que tratas de realizar no es posible hasta el día de hoy (API 24).

Puedes revisarlo en la guía de desarrollo Android [Notificaciones](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html).

Lo que podrías hacer con la imagen es unicamente mostrarla de esta forma, definiendo [BigPictureStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.BigPictureStyle.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Actualización:

Con respecto a la imagen que anexas puedes crear un layout adecuado como `mi_layout.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/foca" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Rehabilitate Sick and Injured Seal Pups\World Oceans Week\n$1 means 1 pound of fish for a  hungry seal pup"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#879BA6"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

El cual generaría una vista similar a la que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo puedes agregar a tu notificación a travez de un **[RemoteView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)**:

```
RemoteViews myRemoteView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.mi_layout);  
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContent(myRemoteView);
```

Revisa esta respuesta de como crear una [notificación personalizada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168704/250260) de @DhawalSodhaParmar definiendo una **[RemoteView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)**.

Comment: Elena, ahi edite la pregunta con un ejemplo de una aplicacion que si tiene las notificaciones de la forma que busco hacerlas.

Comment: Gracia Nicolas he agregado la actualización a mi respuesta.